# Wordpress: Pre-path mode for a multilanguage solution ("/en/", "/de/")

Tags: wordpress, multilingual

I need to have a pattern in the url on the whole website to control which language is shown. The pattern www.website.com/en/permalink should generate a variable like $lang="en".

I have tried different approaches like `add_rewrite_rule`, `add_rewrite_endpoint`or adding rewrite rules via  `add_filter('rewrite_rules_array')` and using `preg_match`to generate the actual pattern from the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. 
I also had a look on plugins like `qtranslate` that does very well what i need but the sourcecode is too complex for me to understand.

After all, I dont understand how to do this in a good way, what is the best approach to achieve this?

The language pattern has to stay in the URL on the whole page, like in `qtranslate`, f.e. after clicking a menu-link the pattern has to be shown in the url again.

The solution has to be SEO-friendly.

Answer (score -1):

If you aren't confident doing this, the quickest way is to get the WPML (wordpress multi-language) plug-in.

Comment: thanks I know WPML and i dont want to use it, f.e. due to performance. I have written my own solution based on custom fields the only thing that is missing is a nice solution for the url to replace the $_GET arguments in the url